# wordpress remove home icon woocommerce artificer menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, woocommerce, html

The free woocommerce theme artificer has an ugly home icon button that I would like to remove.  Here is the page for the theme so you can see what the button looks like:
http://www.woothemes.com/products/artificer/

I tried searching around and found one person who said to make a new menu bar, which I did, although it still had the icon on it.

Comment: If it has a unique ID (or is otherwise addressable through classes etc.), you may be able to hide the button in CSS using `display: none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#navigation ul.nav li.home a { 
    display:none; 
}`

Answer (score 0):

I think it looks OK actually :-)

But anyway, just add this to your custom CSS. You might be able to do this in the theme settings somewhere. If not, just set up a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and put this at the bottom of the CSS file:

```
#navigation ul.nav li.home a span {
  background-image:none;
  text-indent:0;
}
```

Comment: That got me closer, although that just made the same button into a button of the same color but with the Text Home.

Comment: And that isn't that what you wanted? I must have misunderstood the question, sorry.

Comment: This got me what I was looking for:#navigation ul.nav li.home a {
  display:none;
}